# SyntaxError: invalid syntax , operation can't be performed on a column of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a list called Y_pred which contains 7 elements. For each of that element I do some mathematical operations on a column, named 'Purchase Price' of a csv file and want to store the result in a new column called 'new' in the csv. For that I wrote a code:

```
def selling_price(purchase, margin):
    return purchase + purchase*margin

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', engine='python')
df['new'] = df['Purchase Price'].apply(selling_price(df[Purchase Price], Y_pred))
```

The csv file looks like this:

[image]

`print(Y_pred)` produces this:

```
[[0.09528435]
 [0.07486867]
 [0.12372819]
 [0.11737926]
 [0.11570468]
 [0.09456172]
 [0.09490446]]
```

I am getting this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-121-fdcc7bcd17fb>", line 7
    df['new'] = df['Purchase Price'].apply(selling_price(df[Purchase Price], Y_pred))
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing `''` - need `df['Purchase Price']`

Comment: Dont you miss quotes there?

Comment: still error: Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: @jezrael : what is x?

Comment: `df['new'] = df['Purchase Price'].apply(lambda x: selling_price(x, Y_pred))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code missing `''`, but need another solution - `lambda function`:

```
df['new'] = df['Purchase Price'].apply(lambda x: selling_price(x, Y_pred))
```

For increase performance is better store in pandas columns scalars, not lists or arrays.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Purchase Price':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
})

def selling_price(purchase, margin):
    return purchase + purchase*margin

Y_pred = np.array([[0.09528435],
 [0.07486867],
 [0.12372819],
 [0.11737926],
 [0.11570468],
 [0.09456172],
 [0.09490446]])

df['new'] = df['Purchase Price'].apply(lambda x: selling_price(x, Y_pred))
print (df)
   Purchase Price                                                new
0               4  [[4.3811374], [4.29947468], [4.49491276], [4.4...
1               5  [[5.47642175], [5.37434335], [5.61864095], [5....
2               4  [[4.3811374], [4.29947468], [4.49491276], [4.4...
3               5  [[5.47642175], [5.37434335], [5.61864095], [5....
4               5  [[5.47642175], [5.37434335], [5.61864095], [5....
5               4  [[4.3811374], [4.29947468], [4.49491276], [4.4...
```

EDIT:

Better/faster solution is working in numpy instead yuour function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Purchase Price':[4,5,4,5,5,4],

})


Y_pred = np.array([[0.09528435],
 [0.07486867],
 [0.12372819],
 [0.11737926],
 [0.11570468],
 [0.09456172],
 [0.09490446]])

purchase = df['Purchase Price'].values[:, None] 
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(purchase * Y_pred[:, 0]+purchase,index=df.index).add_prefix('New_'))
print (df)

   Purchase Price     New_0     New_1     New_2     New_3     New_4     New_5  \
0               4  4.381137  4.299475  4.494913  4.469517  4.462819  4.378247   
1               5  5.476422  5.374343  5.618641  5.586896  5.578523  5.472809   
2               4  4.381137  4.299475  4.494913  4.469517  4.462819  4.378247   
3               5  5.476422  5.374343  5.618641  5.586896  5.578523  5.472809   
4               5  5.476422  5.374343  5.618641  5.586896  5.578523  5.472809   
5               4  4.381137  4.299475  4.494913  4.469517  4.462819  4.378247   

      New_6  
0  4.379618  
1  5.474522  
2  4.379618  
3  5.474522  
4  5.474522  
5  4.379618
```

Comment: I want : each value of Y_pred to work on all values of the column of that csv, and produce the 'new' column. So there should be 7 such columns in csv named 'new'. is that possible?

Comment: @Debbie - Sure, give me some time.